# for of loop querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, for-loop, mozilla, selectors-api

Mozilla states that "for of loops will loop over NodeList objects correctly". (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) However, this doesn't work in Chrome 43. Is this incorrect documentation or a browser bug?

The copied example code used on a page with checkboxes:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type=checkbox]' );
for (var item of list) {
  item.checked = true;
}
```

Comment: Could we have a bit more context? Can you give us an example or anything?

Comment: I’d like to know what exactly doesn’t work in Chrome. Does it throw a syntax error? Does it check none of the checkboxes?

Comment: [`for..of` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) only support objects that are [implemented as iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), containing a `Symbol.iterator` key/method. Currently, in Chrome, `console.log(Symbol.iterator in list); // false`.

Comment: @Xufox it throws "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit: [This is shipping in Chrome 51](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5750902036103168).

[Jake Archibald posted a simple fix](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/iterators-gonna-iterate/#nodelist-iteration):

```
NodeList.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator]
```

And for of loops.

Comment: Same applies to others like `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: It is inherently dangerous to alter environment and this suggestion is doing exactly that. Better just cast querySelectorAll to Array in place:

`for (let element of [...document.querySelectorAll('selector')]) {...}`

Answer (score 6):

The docs are correct, but I wouldn't call this a bug. Rather it's a "not yet implemented feature".

There is no standard for this, and there is still active discussion on how the DOM should integrate with ES6. Notice that it is clear *that* `querySelectorAll` should return something iterable which can be used in a `for of` loop (as the common expectation demands), but it's not clear *how* that should happen (Let `NodeList` implement the Iterable interface? Let some [`Elements` collection](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#element-collections) subclass `Array`?).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.from`

```
let _list = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

let list = Array.from(_list);

for (let item of list) {
  //... just like an array
  item.checked = true
}
```

or more shortly

```
let list = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

for (let item of Array.from(list)) {
  item.checked = true
}
```

**Important note** `Array.from` was introduced in Chrome 45 [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Comment: How is that better? You need to call Array.from every time.

Comment: Yes, it's true that you have to call `Array.from` every single time (and maybe include a polyfill for that), but with this method you aren't trying to extend the DOM.

Comment: What does this have to do with extending the DOM?

Answer (score 2):

Since I've successfully used `for..of` in Gecko to iterate `NodeList`s, it seems this is a browser bug, or at least a browser lack.

Actual working code from a userscript I currently use:

```
let llnk = document.querySelectorAll("div#threadlist a.threadtitle_unread");
for (let lnk of llnk) {
    //...
}
```

(This also uses `let`, but that's another story.)

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing [`Array.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries)

```js
var list = [].entries.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"));

for (item of list) {
  item[1].checked = true;
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" /><input type="checkbox" />
```

You could also use `Array.prototype.values()`

```js
var list = [].values.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"));

for (item of list) {
  item.checked = true;
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" /><input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another solution for the modern age:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")].forEach(node => {
     node.textContent = "foo";
});
```

This takes advantage of the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) which is supported in Google Chrome 46+, Firefox 16+, and Edge, and just for fun the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: What is the purpose of reconstructing the array?

Comment: The result of `querySelectorAll` is a NodeList, not an array. By converting it we can easily iterate over it.

Comment: What difference does it make now? They are both iterable.

Comment: As other answers have pointed out, unless you assign the iterator of an Array to a NodeList, some browsers will give you problems (hence your original question). I was just offering an alternative clean syntactical way to do a `forEach` iteration instead of using `from` or `call`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do, for a different approach

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"),function(ele,idx)
{
    ele.checked = true;
}
```

good from IE9 and above

Answer (score 0):

Native `Symbol.iterator` support for `NodeList` was [**added**](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/commit/72a2f99e968571989790d58f5b35e8465c52a462) to the [**WHATWG's DOM spec**](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/) in 2014.

Unfortunately, Chrome 51 is the first version of Chrome to support it, and its Beta has only just been released at the time of writing this answer. Also, there's no support in any version of Internet Explorer or Edge.

To add `Symbol.iterator` support for `NodeList` in all browsers to your code, just use the following polyfill :

```
NodeList.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Turns out mine was caused by calling Promise.all() with parameters instead of an array. For example:

Before: `Promise.all(p1, p2)`

After: `Promise.all([p1, p2])`

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: What does this have to do with NodeList?